# How to change Apache user and group from apache to our own user and group in fedora

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, fedora

I have recently changed the user of Apache from `apache` to my own user so that I could be the owner of the project in `www`.
But I don't know why I am not able to access any project after I changed the user and group in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, even localhost
it give me this error

> "Service Unavailable
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

Let me know if there is a way so I could change the default user and group of Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you changed the user the daemon is actually run as in the Apache configuration. You really, really, really don't want to do that. Not only is it not how the package is designed to run — it is also a gigantic security problem.

Presumably what you actually want is to have files in `www` owned and editable by you. Don't do this by changing the apache user. Create a new group, and add *your* user account to it and change ownership of the files appropriately.

If you need Apache to also *write* to files, you can add the apache user to a group like that, too. Be very careful, though, because this is the number one way in which sites get compromised. Make sure the writable files are separate from the files that apache actually *serves*. From my days working in university IT, note that thinking "oh, my site is custom-made and obscure -- no one will hack it" is very, very wrong.